# Error de correo en laravel

Tags: laravel

Al intentar usar las rutas por defecto de laravel me sale este error para mandar el correo de reiniciar mi password:

> Swift_TransportException in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 383: Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.1 Authentication required "

Antes me salia este mensaje:

> error:14090086:ssl routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed

que tampoco se como se resolvió. 
alguna posible solución..

Comment: Creo que es un problema de configuración de las opciones de correo en el archivo `.env`. Mira especialmente el campo `MAIL_ENCRYPTION`.

Answer (score 0):

¿Puedes mostrar la parte del archivo .env que hace referencia al mail?

Si usas gmail deber ser algo parecido a esto:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=MiUsuario@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=MiContraseña
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta esta configuración, esta escrito para codeigniter pero solo usa los valores.

```
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp'; 
$config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com'; 
$config['smtp_user'] = 'rey@rey.com';
$config['smtp_pass'] = 'rey';
$config['smtp_port'] = '465'; 
$config['smtp_timeout'] = '10'; 
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
$config['wrapchars'] = 76; 
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
```

Comment: Especifica mejor tu respuesta y porque soluciona el problema